# cursor: mouse grab javascript

Tags: javascript, cursor, drag, mousedown

I have two images: one with an open hand, and one with a grabbing hand. I was hoping that a simple "onmousedown" and "onmouseup" functions help to make the famous grabbing hand you can see in something like google maps.
BUT...
Sorry, from the beginning: I have a simple DIV with nothing in, apart his background. when I hold down the mouse and start to "drag" the cursor a function is supposed to start and change the cursor form "hand open" to "hand grab". But the cursor become a selector for text istead of what I want.
Any help? this is the example

```
<div onmousedown="function(){this.style.cursor='url(handgrab.png)'}"
onmouseup="function(){this.style.cursor='url(handopen.png)'}"
</div>
```

the only thing I want is change the cursor when dragging the mouse into the DIV.
sorry for this inline choose, but I don't want write all the JS file...

Comment: OK guys, I've founded the big trouble: to the div I have to set the event "onselectstart" to null (or return false). The game is done! Hope this is helpful for other, see you

Answer (score -1):

You should access this through class name. It makes life easier.

Try this way:-

### HTML:

```
<div onmouseup="this.className='openHand'" onmousedown="this.className='closeHand'">
    Mouse Down and Up Events
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

### CSS:

```
.​openHand​ {
    cursor: url(https://mail.google.com/mail/images/2/openhand.cur), default !important;
}

.closeHand {
    cursor: url(https://mail.google.com/mail/images/2/closedhand.cur), default !important;
}​
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/uYC2p/)**

Comment: thanks to the answers. I had some trouble because: 1) when dragging the mouse on the div with background, many time FireFox take the image istead of change cursor, but sometime it work. 2) no way with google chrome, the closed hand doesn't appear. 3) only IE9 seems to work right... incredible